# Dynamic HTML value calculation using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to create a table where dynamic values are displayed in a column depending on values selected by users. Below is my code for it. So basically, depending on the number of adults and number of children that are selected, the Price will be calculated. So if someone chooses 1 adult and 0 children, then the Amount for 2 Day ticket should be $235, for 3 day it will be $301 and so on. I want this done on selection change method of selectboxes. I am also not very familiar with JQuery. How do I accompalish this using JQuery?

```
Ages 10+:


<select id="Adult" name="Adult">
<option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>



Ages 3-9:

<select id="Child" name="Child">
<option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<table width="800" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="224">Product</td>
    <td width="246">Ages 10+</td>
    <td width="192">Ages 3-9</td>
    <td width="110">Price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 Day Ticket</td>
    <td>$235.00</td>
    <td>$223.00</td>
    <td>$<span class="amount"></span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3 Day Ticket</td>
    <td>$301.00</td>
    <td>$285.00</td>
    <td>$<span class="amount"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4 Day Ticket</td>
    <td>$315.00</td>
    <td>$298.00</td>
    <td>$<span class="amount"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5 Day Ticket</td>
    <td>$328.00</td>
    <td>$309.00</td>
    <td>$<span class="amount"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know the calculation, but I do not know how to display it in each td span using JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is complete code to accomplish what you're trying to do.  I added some id's to the totals.  See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Jegn/1/) for a working example.  It would be better to not hard code the values, but this works as a starting point.

```
var numAdult = 0;
var numChild = 0;

$("#Adult").change( function(){
    numAdult = $("#Adult").val();
    calcTotals();
});
$("#Child").change( function() {
    numChild = $("#Child").val();
    calcTotals();
});

function calcTotals(){
    $("#2DayTotal").text(235*numAdult + 223*numChild);
    $("#3DayTotal").text(301*numAdult + 285*numChild);
    $("#4DayTotal").text(315*numAdult + 298*numChild);
    $("#5DayTotal").text(328*numAdult + 309*numChild);
}
```

Comment: Like I said I am very new to JQuery, can you help with the code. I know the calculation but I am not sure where to put what code so that my span amounts display correctly for all <Tr>

Comment: Code is all laid out for you above by NuclearGhost. Needs some styling, but it works as you wanted.

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm. Thank you so much @NuclearGhost. I appreciate all your help with this.

Comment: @developer you're welcome.  This code can definitely be improved to loop over the rows and pull the values, but I wanted to get you started.